# Returning to a chroot environment

Tags: chroot

When I chroot while logged in using a ssh session.  How do I get back to the chroot environment when the ssh terminal session ends.  When I ssh back in I'm back on the non chroot environment.  While I'm in a chroot session and I start a process.  I then exit out of the ssh session.  Later I want to go back to the chroot environment and stop the process and restart it.  Is it just a simple as chroot again to the previous chroot folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you "exit out of the ssh session", you send the process you're connected to a `SIGHUP` (Hangup) signal (from `man 7 signal`):

```
   Signal     Value     Action   Comment
   ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   SIGHUP        1       Term    Hangup detected on controlling terminal
                                 or death of controlling process
```

When this `SIGHUP` is seen by the process on the server, it terminates. :-(

There are a couple ways of working around this feature:

1. Start your `chroot` environment on the server with the `nohup` (`man
   nohup` says `nohup — invoke a utility immune to hangups`).
2. Suspend the local end of your `ssh` session with
   <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>CtrlZ</kbd> after an <kbd>Enter</kbd>, background
   it with `bg`, connection intact, no SIGHUPs. Bring it back into the
   foreground with `fg`. See `man bash` especially the sections on
   `SIGNALS` and `JOB CONTROL`. If you terminate the `ssh` session,
   `SUGHUP` ensues.

Comment: I'm curious if I were to start the sshd in the chroot environment.  Then I should always be in the chroot environment when I ssh into the device. What I'm trying to do is setup a NAS to run off of a USB drive.  When running  from disk it wakes up the disk to often.  When running from the USB it almost never wahes up unless you are actually accessing your data.